# I'm trying to filter fragments using dates

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to filter fragments that display income data that I pull from firebase. Displaying them is no problem. Filtering them however, is difficult to say the least. While the datepickers have no errors when I try filtering it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7KXr.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q1U9.png)

**ViewIncomeFragment.java**

```
//Filter Button
Button filterButton = v.findViewById(R.id.btnFilter);
filterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Filter the Income data
        filterIncomeByDate(startDate, endDate);
        
        // Show a dialog to get start and end date from the user
        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog2 = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                if (endDate != null) {
                    endDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + year);
                }
                if(validateDates() == false){
                    startDate.setText("StartDate");
                    endDate.setText("EndDate");
                }
            }
            // handle the date set event
        }, calendar2.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar2.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        datePickerDialog2.show();

        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog1 = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                if (startDate != null) {
                    startDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + year);
                }
            }
            // handle the date set event
        }, calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        datePickerDialog1.show();
    }
});

return v;
```

```
//Method to filter the Income by date
public void filterIncomeByDate(TextView startDate, TextView endDate){
    ArrayList<Income> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    try {
        Date start = dateFormat.parse(startDate.getText().toString());
        Date end = dateFormat.parse(endDate.getText().toString());
        for (Income income : incomeArrayList) {
            Date incomeDate = dateFormat.parse(income.getDateIncome());
            if (incomeDate.after(start) && incomeDate.before(end)) {
                filteredList.add(income);
            }
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    incomeArrayList.clear();
    incomeArrayList.addAll(filteredList);
    incomeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Only the fragments within the date range should be displaying

Comment: I don't see any calls to the Firebase Realtime Database API in the code you shared. If the fact that the data comes from Firebase is necessary to reproduce the problem, edit your question to show that. If the problem can be reproduced without Firebase, remove that tag. I recommend taking a moment to study [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as following the guidance in there gives the best chance that someone can help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.